# Adding centreX and centreY Constraint programmatically using obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Hi i have a assignment to add constraint programmatically to my logIn page. I have a view controller inside the view controller i added my uitextfield , uilabel , uibutton ..etc.
I want to make my view control to the centre of my main page both in X and Y direction.I am not getting it the correct output.

```
[_logInView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.logInView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.logInView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.logInView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:309]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.logInView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:309]];
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9YZfopxzOv5ME95VTNvN010eWM/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9YZfopxzOv5dWxWV2Zrd2NwSUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: 'not the correct output' isn't really enough info...

Comment: means the centreX and CentreY constraints are not applying to the view controller but the width and height constraints are applying. @wain

Comment: Try swap `self.view` with `self.logInView` in first two constraints?

Comment: NO...its not coming to centre.

Comment: Could you provide some screenshot for correct output which you want, so that I would help you..

Comment: i provided the image link. The second link shows the image what i want. and the first image is my output. @keshavvishwkarma

Comment: Your `self.logInView` is positioned as if its `self.view` is 600 points wide. That is the standard scene size in a storyboard and is not the size of any iPhone screen. I deduce that `self.view` doesn't have the constraints it needs to fit itself to the screen. Use [Xcode's view hierarchy debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html) to check.

Comment: @kalpa, you can also use [KVConstraintExtensionsMaster](https://github.com/keshavvishwkarma/KVConstraintExtensionsMaster) library to add constraints easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can use some custom library to make constraints. I think what standard syntax is not clear and too complicated. I prefer to use library named [KeepLayout](https://github.com/Tricertops/KeepLayout), this library has clear syntax to add constraints. 
For example to add your constraints, you should write only one string:

```
#import <KeepLayout.h>

<....>
[self.logInView keepCentered];
[self.logInView.superview setNeedsLayout]; //because added constraints
```

Comment: It is the full code to configure view as centered view in it's parent view.

Comment: is it objective c?

Comment: Yes, it is Objective-C, (please go to KeepLayout site, I've added link and exam this project). KeepLayout it is third party library, it is not part of iOS or Cocoa SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `withItem` and `toItem` are the wrong away round. The `withItem` is that view you want to apply to the constraint to, so in your case its your `self.loginView`.

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.logInView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.logInView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

Comment: No. the last two constraints are for Width and height. and it should be nil. If i am changing it to self.view then it showing the following error.  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Unknown layout attribute'

Comment: Ah sorry. I see your problem no, will update the answer

Comment: I also tried with the answer before and now also I tried again but not getting the view in centre. And I updated my question with the image you can find the link. please help me. @Lneuner

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend reading up on Apple's new anchor based constraint building kit introduced in iOS9. They make life much easier. Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html).